# Performance difference between a regular string and template string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I am now using ESLint [prefer-template](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template) to force myself use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) instead of string concatenation.

This made me think whether there is ever a need to use regular string over the template string format, e.g.

```js
console.log('Why use this? It requires me to escape different quotes depending on the context. In this case  \'.');
console.log(`When I can use this. It allows me to use all types of quotes (e.g. ', ") without ever worrying about escaping them.`);
```

I realise that JSPerf is not ideal profiling tool, though at least in the case of a static string, I cannot observe any performance penalty, e.g. http://jsperf.com/es-string-vs-template.

Comment: Turns out ESLint [quotes](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes) rule already support "backtick" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there should not be any performance difference.

You just have to make sure to escape `` ` `` and  `${` instead of `'` or `"`.